# Is there any advantage of adding async keyword in the start of an ASP.NET Core Web API method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I didn't find much on the web. I think when there is high volume of incoming requests, marking the Web API method as `async` can help in managing request throttling. It allows the server to handle more requests concurrently, which can be crucial for ensuring that no request is unnecessarily delayed due to thread blocking.

I need the Stackoverflow community advice on this topic.

Comment: That's precisely the main point why you should write Web API methods as async methods - optimize the overall system throughput by avoiding blocking threads for long periods of time just waiting for results to come in ...

Comment: The point of declaring a method `async` is to use `await` in it. If you're not using `await`, there's no point to `async`. Of course, you almost certainly should be using `await` and, if you're not, the rest of your is probably not well designed.

Comment: @jmcilhinney. In those scenario where a WEB API method is marked as async without await. Still there is an advantage like in terms of request throttling, it allows the server to potentially return the thread to the thread pool and free to be utilized by other API calls. This is particularly advantageous in scenarios with a high volume of API calls

Comment: See e.g. https://code-maze.com/asynchronous-programming-with-async-and-await-in-asp-net-core/ or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=COeg6UoPe_Q for more explanations behind the motivation and benefits of using async/await

Comment: @Anwar, this is false. Marking a method `async` without using `await` in it makes absolutely no difference in how the method behaves or how the server processes requests. If you know better, then you're welcome to answer your own question with what you've found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the **only** change you make is adding `async` to a method, then No.
The point of declaring a method async is to use `await` in it. If you're not using await, there's no point to async.

When doing so, the performance gain will be in freeing the thread to handle other requests while it awaits an I/O request to complete (e.g. making a request over the network, reading from disc, etc..)